# How to select the div which the item is being dragged into on hover, using jQuery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Ok so I have a normal jQuery UI sortable, and I need to select the div in which I'm dropping my element into. I normally get this by using ui.item.parent('div') in the received event.

However, on the over event that variable relates to the sender of the element (where it has been dragged from) rather than what it is hovering over. So how do I select where I am dropping my element.

An example I have at the moment that just prints  the parent element's offset:

```
$(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    over:function(event,ui){

        console.log(ui.item.closest('div').offset())
},
connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

edit:

I created a really simple example to show what I am doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Zbwc/4/

Basically when you drag a row from the first table to the next one you see in the console that it has offset.left as 0. I need the offset.left of the new table.

Comment: Can you supply a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can see what you're working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a placeholder and then select the parent of the placeholder class.

http://jsfiddle.net/BnZMA/

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    over:function(event,ui){
        console.log($('.placeholder').parent().attr('id'));
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work nicely, what exactly is the placeholder anyway?

Comment: When dragging a sortable item to a new location, other items will make room for the that item by shifting to allow white space between them. Pass a class into the placeholder option to style that space to be visible. Use the boolean forcePlaceholderSize option to set dimensions on the placeholder. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder)